# <Unable to read memory> while using fstream

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to open a file I created, but I keep getting an  error when I try to open my file.
Here is what the debugger says:

```
std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> > = <Unable to read memory>
```

Basically what happens is that the first time I run the program it runs fine, but then the second time it crashes when trying to read the file previously created. It throws an exception :

Unhandled exception at 0x012F1539 in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003.

Here is the function that throws the exception:

```
int convert(string balance, int lineno){ // Funciton to convert strings in file to ints---------------------------------
//Getting information from the file about locations

int *pointer;
pointer = findNewLines();
static int linenopos[11];
try{

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        linenopos[i] = *(pointer + i);
    }
}
catch (const std::exception& e){
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
int balanceInt;

try {
    balanceFile.open("E:\\MoneyStuff\\balance.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

//Opening file
balanceFile.open("E:\\MoneyStuff\\balance.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

//Getting Balances
balanceFile.seekg(linenopos[(lineno - 1)], ios::beg);
getline(balanceFile, balance);

balanceFile.close();

stringstream convert(balance);//Variable to convert string balance to integer balance

//Converting balance string to int
convert >> balanceInt;

//Setting balanceInt to 0 if the file doesn't exist
if (balanceInt < -30000)
    balanceInt = 0;

return balanceInt;
}
```

And here is the function that it calls (just in case that's the problem):

```
int * findNewLines(){ //Function to find the \n characters in the txt file----------------------------------------------
//Creating Variables for function
static int linenopos[11];//Vector to store line positions in
char c; //Variable for checking character value
int pos; //Variable for temporarily storing position
int lineno = 0; //Integer to tell which line to read

//Writing in first line position
linenopos[0] = 0;
lineno++;

balanceiFile.open("E:\\MoneyStuff\\balance.txt", ios::binary);
do{
    balanceiFile.get(c);
    if (c == '\n'){
        pos = balanceiFile.tellg();
        linenopos[lineno] = pos;
        lineno++;
    }
} while (balanceiFile.good());

//Resetting error flags
balanceiFile.clear();

return linenopos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out the second `balanceFile.open` statement?

I would probably also include a control statement like `if (balanceFile)` so that you know you're reading good data. If you compile with -g do you get a line number that the error is on?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that will help:

1. Decide if you want to keep the file open and open it just once, or if you want to open and close it multiple times and close it each time.
2. Fix the spelling of 'balanceiFile'  ( Why does this compile? )
3. Store the number of lines found, and check that it does not exceed the length of the array
4. Check that the line requested is less than or equal to the number of lines found.